# Python list subtraction

Tags: python

This is the practice example :

> Write a function `(list1, list2)` that takes in two lists as arguments and return a list that is the result of removing elements from `list1` that can be found in `list2`.

Why does this function return `[1, 3, 4]` and not `[4]` as I thought it would? I think it has something to do with `list1.remove()`. I guess it's something obvious, but I can't see it.

It works on these examples:

```
subtractList (['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['x', 'y', 'z']) =
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

subtractList([1,2,3,4,5], [2, 4]) =
    [1, 3, 5]
```

but fails on this:

```
subtractList(range(5), range(4))
```

Also i noticed it removes only even numbers from the list.

Here is the code:

```
def subtractList(list1,list2):
    list1 = list(list1)
    list2 = list(list2)

    for i in list1:
        if i in list2:
            list1.remove(i)

    return list1
```

I have solved this practice with:

```
def subtractList(list1,list2):

    new_list = []

    list1 = list(list1)
    list2 = list(list2)

    for i in list1:
        if i not in list2:
            new_list.append(i)

    return new_list
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting, in particular your indentation. As it stands it is difficult to help you.

Comment: Are you using Python 3 or Python 2?

Comment: Also, since you're already passing in lists (range(x) is also a list) turning them into lists again (`list1 = list(list1)`) is unnecessary

Comment: Inconsistent edits :(

Comment: Python3,yes range returns also a list by i wanted to be sure if someone enters something like tuple it would still work

Comment: Good thinking, but both my list comprehension solution and your function solution will work on tuples anyway.

Comment: Is this 'pure' subtraction such that `[1, 1, 1, 1]-[1]=[1, 1, 1]` or is it set removal such that `[1, 1, 2, 2]-[1]=[2, 2]`

Comment: Yes i actualy prefer your solution,simple one line.

Comment: You need to return elements that are not in both lists so its basicaly like sets difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing a list as you iterate over it will cause problems.  Your second solution is decent, or you can check out "list comprehensions".  In this case:

```
new_list = [num for num in list1 if num not in list2]
```

Comment: For what it's worth, for a Python beginner I don't think the cause for your error is something obvious at all.  :)

Answer (score 4):

Impress your professor by cheating:

```
def subtract_list(l1, l2):
    return list(sorted(set(l1) - set(l2)))
```

Comment: yes i also thought about sets lol

Comment: This may change the order of list1.